# Trying to use a point->list fit in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

SO I've been working on trying to fit a point to a 3-dimensional list.

```
x= val
Y=[x,y,z]

model.fit(x,y)
```

The fitting part is giving me errors with dimensionality (even after I did reshaping and all the other shenanigans online). Is it a lost cause or is there something that I can do? I've been using sklearn so far.

Comment: What is the error you get and what are the x,y,z dimensions? are they list or single values?

Comment: x,y,z are int values and the error was "Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead"

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sklearn documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) for regression models:

> `fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None)[source]`
>
> Parameters X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples,
>   n_features) Training data
>
> yarray-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_targets) Target
>   values. Will be cast to X’s dtype if necessary

So both `X` and `y` should be arrays. It might not make sense to train your model with a single value, but in order to resolve the error, you can train it like:

```py
model.fit([x], [y])
```

if your model is a linear one. Otherwise, it really depends on your model. So, if you are going to train a 3D model, and your model only accepts 2D inputs, you should feed it with 2D inputs.